# how can i find unique row so i can count only if value not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql

i got those rows for example

```
id phoneNum status     date
1  123456   no answer
2  123456   no answer
3  123456   no answer
4  123456   no answer
5  123456   no answer
6  123456   no answer
7  123456   ANSWERED


8   567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
9   567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
10  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
11  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
12  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
13  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05
14  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:35:05


15  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
16  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
17  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
18  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
19  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
20  567890   no answer  2020-11-19 10:40:00
21  567890   ANSWERED   2020-11-19 10:40:00
```

for that example i want to count only if none of the rows are ANSWERED
and from that example i will get 1 as results because phone number 567890 was not ANSWERED at all
the phoneNum is incoming phone number and its ringing in few extensions so my DB is getting all
the data about each call and i need to count how many call not answered.

what is the SELECT statement that i need to get that result

thanks :)

Comment: So what you want to know is that IF it has NOT a single answered you to get that phone number and have it print only once? Am I correct?

Comment: if you replace "no answer" and "answered" with (for example) zero and one {0, 1}, then you could `GROUP BY` phoneNum and look for `MIN` or `MAX` status. As in the link commented by @Strawberry , the full table schema would be a relevant thing to provide, as would your prior SQL query attempts.

Comment: thanks for the replay , when i asking a question in stuck overflow its only after i tried any possible way , im not very proffesional in mysql , my example look simple but its not simple as it looks, i tried with distinct , group by and didnt find the right way.

Comment: Eduardo , yes and i want to count it as 1 for that example , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `'no answer'` and `'ANSWERED'` are the only possible values for the column `status`, if you want the `phoneNum`s for which there isn't any row with `status = 'ANSWERED'`, then group by phone number and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT phoneNum
FROM tablename
GROUP BY phoneNum
HAVING SUM(status = 'ANSWERED') = 0
```

If you want to count the phone numbers for which there isn't any row with `status = 'ANSWERED'`, then use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phoneNum) counter
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE phoneNum = t.phoneNum AND status = 'ANSWERED')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=17afe2c5fe88acf8c8b66951121b8a09).

Comment: I still got an issue with the results , if the same number calls again and got answer then the counter is geting minus 1 because of the distinct source , i want to count only no answer from differnet date time, thanks for any help

Comment: Add one more condition: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE phoneNum = t.phoneNum AND date = t.date AND status = 'ANSWERED')`